# Is it true that is $\lambda \min\{a,b\}=\min\{\lambda a,\lambda b\}$ where $a ,b$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R^{+}}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true that $\lambda \min\{a,b\}=\min\{\lambda a,\lambda b\}$
where $a,b$ and  $\lambda \in \mathbb{R^{+}}$? If is it true how to prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. What's the definition of $\min\{a, b\}$?

If $a > b$, then $\min\{a, b\} = ?$...

If $b > a$, then...

If $a = b$, then...

Multiply all three cases by $\lambda$. Now what is $\min\{\lambda a, \lambda b\}$? (Use the same process as above, extended.)